# Multiple IF OR conditions in Excel formula

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

In Excel I made a formula based on a MAX condition if several conditions are true. So far the formula looks:

```
    =MAX(IF(A:A="Nissan";IF(B:B="Green";C:C)))
```

Now, I would like a formula based on multiple colors, for example Green and Blue Nissans. I can not figure out where I have to place the color Blue.

[image]

I use Excel 2007 and know to use CTRL+SHFT+ENTER for this formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works - still need to use ctrl+shift+enter:

```
=MAX(IF(A:A="Nissan";IF(OR(B:B="Green";B:B="Blue");C:C)))
```

Tested and works, I had to pay attention to the ";" and ","...

Borrowing the {} from JvdV below, this works:

```
=MAX(IF(A:A="Nissan";IF((B:B={"Green";"Blue"});C:C)))
```

Comment: Comes in handy even when you want to extend the criteria of column A, you can apply the same format e.g. `{"Nissan";"Chevrolet"}`

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 2016, you could use `MAXIFS()` and feed the formula a list of values. Particularly handy if you have more than two criteria for column A or B or both.

```
=MAXIFS(C3:C10,A3:A10,"Nissan",B3:B10,{"Blue","Green"})
```

Comment: I noticed just before I posted ... but keep it as others will benefit.